# Java Spring Table Relations

Tags: java, spring

I have a class named **Employee** and each employee responsible from some of accounts. But not all accounts have employee assigned.

Because some of the accounts belongs to companies.

How can I create this relation?

Employee Class :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_person", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_person", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated
    private JobTitle jobTitle;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_address_id")
    private List<Address> address;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_account_id")
    private List<Account> accounts;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_auth_account_id")
    private List<Account> authorizedAccounts;

    public enum JobTitle {
        ACCOUNT_MANAGER, CONSUMER_MANAGER, BUSINESS_MANAGER
    }
}
```

Account Class :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_person_address", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_person_address", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated
    private AccountType accountType;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private List<Client> clients;

    private enum AccountType {
        INTERNAL, CONSUMER, SMALL_BUSINESS, LARGE_BUSINESS
    }
}
```

If the account belongs to a small business or large business, there should be an employee assigned.

I checked some website but I couldn't find any answer online. I am not sure if there is any relation like that exist in Spring or not.

Comment: Can a single account be assigned to more than one employee?

Comment: Well, each account can be assigned to clients but not to employee. There has to be only an employee. That was the other tricky part too. Each Client has an account and can be assigned to authorize accounts and some of the clients doesn't have any accounts to authorize.